# Transfer pandas df to db.sqlite3 using django models

Tags: python, django, pandas, sqlite, python-3.6

I have dfs with the following column headers:

```
Year JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC WIN SPR SUM AUT ANN ATTRIBUTE LOCATION
```

Each column contains random floating point value, except for ATTRIBUTE, which contains a value from this list:

```
[Max_temp, Min_temp, Mean_temp, Sunshine, Rainfall]
```

- and LOCATION, which contains a value from this list:

  [UK, England, Scotland, Wales]

I need to put it into the sqlite3 database that comes with django using the following models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator


class Location(models.Model):
    LOCATIONS = (
        ('EN', 'England'),
        ('SC', 'Scotland'),
        ('WA', 'Wales'),
        ('UK', 'United Kingdom'),
    )
    location = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=LOCATIONS)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Location"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location

class Max_temp(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.IntegerField(
    default=0,
    validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999), MinValueValidator(0)]
)
    MONTH_OR_SEASON = (
        ("JAN", "January"),
        ("FEB", "February"),
        ("MAR", "March"),
        ("APR", "April"),
        ("MAY", "May"),
        ("JUN", "June"),
        ("JUL", "July"),
        ("AUG", "August"),
        ("SEP", "September"),
        ("OCT", "October"),
        ("NOV", "November"),
        ("DEC", "December"),
        ("WIN", "Winter"),
        ("SPR", "Spring"),
        ("SUM", "Summer"),
        ("AUT", "Autumn"),
        ("ANN", "Annual"),
)
    month_or_season = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=MONTH_OR_SEASON)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Maximum Temperature"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.year

class Min_temp(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.IntegerField(
    default=0,
    validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999), MinValueValidator(0)]
)
    MONTH_OR_SEASON = (
        ("JAN", "January"),
        ("FEB", "February"),
        ("MAR", "March"),
        ("APR", "April"),
        ("MAY", "May"),
        ("JUN", "June"),
        ("JUL", "July"),
        ("AUG", "August"),
        ("SEP", "September"),
        ("OCT", "October"),
        ("NOV", "November"),
        ("DEC", "December"),
        ("WIN", "Winter"),
        ("SPR", "Spring"),
        ("SUM", "Summer"),
        ("AUT", "Autumn"),
        ("ANN", "Annual"),
)
    month_or_season = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=MONTH_OR_SEASON)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Minimum Temperature"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.year

class Mean_temp(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.IntegerField(
    default=0,
    validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999), MinValueValidator(0)]
)
    MONTH_OR_SEASON = (
        ("JAN", "January"),
        ("FEB", "February"),
        ("MAR", "March"),
        ("APR", "April"),
        ("MAY", "May"),
        ("JUN", "June"),
        ("JUL", "July"),
        ("AUG", "August"),
        ("SEP", "September"),
        ("OCT", "October"),
        ("NOV", "November"),
        ("DEC", "December"),
        ("WIN", "Winter"),
        ("SPR", "Spring"),
        ("SUM", "Summer"),
        ("AUT", "Autumn"),
        ("ANN", "Annual"),
)
    month_or_season = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=MONTH_OR_SEASON)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Mean Temperature"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.year

class Sunshine(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.IntegerField(
    default=0,
    validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999), MinValueValidator(0)]
)
    MONTH_OR_SEASON = (
        ("JAN", "January"),
        ("FEB", "February"),
        ("MAR", "March"),
        ("APR", "April"),
        ("MAY", "May"),
        ("JUN", "June"),
        ("JUL", "July"),
        ("AUG", "August"),
        ("SEP", "September"),
        ("OCT", "October"),
        ("NOV", "November"),
        ("DEC", "December"),
        ("WIN", "Winter"),
        ("SPR", "Spring"),
        ("SUM", "Summer"),
        ("AUT", "Autumn"),
        ("ANN", "Annual"),
)
    month_or_season = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=MONTH_OR_SEASON)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Sunshine"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.year

class Rainfall(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.IntegerField(
    default=0,
    validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999), MinValueValidator(0)]
)
    MONTH_OR_SEASON = (
        ("JAN", "January"),
        ("FEB", "February"),
        ("MAR", "March"),
        ("APR", "April"),
        ("MAY", "May"),
        ("JUN", "June"),
        ("JUL", "July"),
        ("AUG", "August"),
        ("SEP", "September"),
        ("OCT", "October"),
        ("NOV", "November"),
        ("DEC", "December"),
        ("WIN", "Winter"),
        ("SPR", "Spring"),
        ("SUM", "Summer"),
        ("AUT", "Autumn"),
        ("ANN", "Annual"),
)
    month_or_season = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=MONTH_OR_SEASON)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Rainfall"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.year
```

I'm a bit stumped on how to do this - I'm not sure if my model structure is right? And is there a way to structure the models so I don't have to repeat code? I need a database structured like so:

> Location - Max_temp
>            - Min_temp
>            - Mean_temp
>            - Sunshine
>            - Rainfall

So each location has a Max_temp table, a Min_temp table etc...

The main thing tho, is how do I tell Django to put the pandas df into the database and where in the Django project do I put that code?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: There seems to be a fair amount of data attributes missing from your example pandas DF. It's not really possible to recommend model structures without knowing your use case

Comment: Could you show a sample row from pandas and how would you want in in your tables?

Comment: Sorry have edited - I hope that's clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were right to question your model structure :) Typically when you have that much code duplication there is an easier way. Key here is the fact that your measurements all have the same schema. Each model you define represents a database table, and we really don't need to create a new database table for each measurement type- we can just store the type as a column in a "Measurement" table.

I also question whether you need the separate table for `Location` as all it contains is the verbose name for the country code- you may as well use a `ChoiceField` (if your usecase is more advanced than this then feel free to keep the location model separate).

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator


class Measurement(models.Model):
    MEASUREMENT_TYPES = (
        ("max_temp", "Maximum Temperature"),
        ("min_temp", "Minimum Temperature"),
        ("mean_temp", "Mean Temperature"),
        ("sunshine", "Sunshine"),
        ("rainfall", "Rainfall"),
    )

    LOCATIONS = (
        ('EN', 'England'),
        ('SC', 'Scotland'),
        ('WA', 'Wales'),
        ('UK', 'United Kingdom'),
    )

    MONTH_OR_SEASON = (
        ("JAN", "January"),
        ("FEB", "February"),
        ("MAR", "March"),
        ("APR", "April"),
        ("MAY", "May"),
        ("JUN", "June"),
        ("JUL", "July"),
        ("AUG", "August"),
        ("SEP", "September"),
        ("OCT", "October"),
        ("NOV", "November"),
        ("DEC", "December"),
        ("WIN", "Winter"),
        ("SPR", "Spring"),
        ("SUM", "Summer"),
        ("AUT", "Autumn"),
        ("ANN", "Annual"),
    )

    measurement_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, choices=MEASUREMENT_TYPES, default="max_temp",
    )
    location = models.CharField(
        max_length=2, choices=LOCATIONS, default="EN",
    )
    year = models.IntegerField(
        default=0,
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999), MinValueValidator(0)],
    )
    month_or_season = models.CharField(
        max_length=3, choices=MONTH_OR_SEASON, default="ANN",
    )
    value = models.FloatField(
        default=0,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} in {1} - {2}, {3}".format(
            self.measurement_type, self.location,
            self.month_or_season, self.year, 
        )
```

Now when you loop over each row in your dataframe, you get the `ATTRIBUTE` value (you can cast it to `.lower()` to be in-line  with the `MEASUREMENT_TYPES` choices defined in your `models.py`) and the `LOCATION`,  and for each value in `JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC WIN SPR SUM AUT ANN` you create a new `Measurement` with that attribute, location and month/season and the value from that column.

To create a new `Measurement` object you can just do:

```
for row in my_data_frame:
    attribute = row['ATTRIBUTE']  # (or whatever)
    location = row['LOCATION']
    ...
    for month_or_season in MONTH_AND_SEASONS:
        value = row[month_or_season]
        ....
        Measurement(
            measurement_type=attribute,
            location=location,
            value=value,
            ...
        ).save()  # Saves model instance to database
```

Comment: This is great, but can you explain the return "{0} in {1} - {2}, {3}".format(
            self.measurement_type, self.location,
            self.month_or_season, self.year, 
        ) syntax? I'm not sure what that's doing?

Comment: Also is looping over the df efficient? There has to be a built-in function I can call that speed up computation time for large dfs?

Comment: that's using pythons built in string formatting (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) to build a string using the models attributes

Comment: There may well be a more efficient way of doing it than looping, but I don't know enough about pandas- either way you will end up picking out these attributes

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows appears to be the fastest way to loop over a dataframe

Comment: OK 1 last thing - I keep trying to find how to get the df data and put it into the database - what is the code that says "put this piece of data into this field of the database" or 'put this row of the df into this row of the database"? I don't want to use forms, I just want to POST the data into the db